# Do we need a Play Console account to show admob banner and interstitial ads?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I'm created my application in android studio and attach banner and interstitial ads with Test id after successfully build my app i use my admob ad unit id of banner and interstitial but 10 days go already and my ads not displaying.

1. Do we need a play Console account compulsory to display ads?
2. i have 1 image and one button in my layout , how many content we need to have display ads in my app?
   because i see many videos on YouTube they say we need content in your apps.
3. My friend have a Play Console account i use there (keystore) .jsk file to signed my application after signed apps start displaying ads also i use "Apk Editor Pro" to sign apk its start displaying ads . how?

Please help me out to fix this. thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can try show ads withou google play console.
2. Yes, you need create more content in your app, unique content.
3. -